# On a generic class of type T, how to find E if T is List<E>

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class parameterized with `T`. It holds data of type `T` and has a few methods using type `T`. However, *if* `T` happens to be a `List<E>`, I'd like to be able to write a method where I can use this `E` as a type, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do that.

As an example, consider this:

```
class Test<T> {
  private T data;
  public void setData(T t) {data = t;}
  public T getData() { return data; }
}
```

Now imagine this is instantiated as `Test<List<String>>`. So we have an object with a `getData` method returning a `List<String>`. On this object I would like to also have a method like `setCallback` taking something like `Callback<String>`. In other words, I need a method taking as its argument an interface parameterized with `E` where  `E` relates to `T` as in `List<E> == T`.

How can I write this method?

Note that I do *not* want to force `T` into being a `List` by e.g. declaring `T` as `List<E>` on a class level, it must be possible to use the class both `Test<Integer>` and `Test<List<String>>`, but only in the latter case should the `setCallback` method make sense.

The closest thing I've come up with is this:

```
interface AbstractCallback<T> {}

interface Callback<E> extends AbstractCallback<List<E>> {
  void onSomethingHappened(E e);
}

class Test<T> {
  ...
  void setCallback(AbstractCallback<T> callback);
}
```

On this, I can do

```
Test<List<String>> test = new Test<>();
test.setCallback(new Callback<String>() {
  public void onSomethingHappened(String e) {}
});
```

This works, and if T is *not* a List I won't be able to create a fitting `Callback`, as desired (since it's simply not possible to create an instance of `Callback` that implements `AbstractCallback<T>` unless `T` is a List). However, being forced to have the `setCallback` method take the abstract super-class (interface actually) rather than the more concrete one makes the interface unclear and somewhat ambigious.

I have also considered placing `setCallback` on a sub-class of Test such that `class SubTest<E> extends Test<List<E>>` but this means I have to instantiate this class instead of `Test`, and even if I delegate construction of `Test` objects to a factory, the type of `T` is not known at time of construction (unless I add `Class` arguments to carry type information, which I'd rather not) - it will only be known after `setData` has been called. Also, I prefer if clients only have to refer to `Test` and not bother with down-casting etc.

Finally, I have considered just letting the client be responsible for supplying the correct type by just definining `E` as an unbound generic type unrelated to `T`, and simply let incorrect calls result in ClassCastExceptions:

```
<E> void setCallback(Callback<E> callback);
```

Is there a better way of doing this? To re-cap, basically I want to declare a generic method with a generic type `E` related to the class' generic type `T` so that `T` is equivalent to `List<E>`; and, ideally, if T is *not* a List at all, the method is not possible to invoke. So you could say this is the *opposite* of having a class of `E` and declaring a method with `List<E>` or even `<T extends List<E>>`. 
I imagine it may not be possible since at compile-time there is no way to tell if `T` is a List or not, but maybe there is a more clever way around it than my suggestion above?

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. But maybe this may help you... You can write a method declaration such as `public <E, T extends List<E>> somethingWith(CallBack<T>)`. Note however that due to type erasure, this method cannot have the same name as the method for which the type argument is not a `List` of something.

Comment: Hmm, but this way, neither E or T has any relation to the generic type of the class, which I also called T?
(Also, I want the callback to operate on E, not on T, so that if the class holds Lists of Strings, this method would take Callback<String>).

Comment: Then create a separate class for the event when the generic type is meant to be a collection. I don't know the exact intent of your API, but do note that if caller methods don't care about the type parameter you can just use a wildcard.

Comment: I listed that as an alternative which I didn't really like. Also, it would either force the caller to manually construct the correct sub-class in order to get access to the setCallback method (new SubTest<String> instead of new Test<List<String>>), or pass along the Class object of T to a factory method used to determine if T instanceof List, since until setData is called, there is no object to infer type information from. Also it would probably mean clients would have to bother with downcasts.

Comment: If `T` were not a list, would the type of the callback be `Callback<T>` then (instead of `Callback<E>`)?  Or wouldn't there be any callback at all? Both indicate that you'd probably need two classes (maybe with some shared super class) that handle collections or single-valued types.

Comment: Why not just use factory methods? Like, I don't know, `.forSingleType(Class<E> theClass)`, `forCollectionOf(Class<E> theClass)`?

Comment: @Thomas ideally the callback would not be possible to invoke, for example by having it limited by generic bounds. In my own solution using an AbstractCallback it would not be possible to invoke the method with a Callback instance on an instance of Test not carrying a List. It would however be possible to invoke the method with another class implementing AbstractCallback, with undefined behaviour.

Comment: @fge My class implements a specification and I'm trying to stay as close to it as possible. To have a separate sub-class makes sense in a lot of ways, but it would require class parameters or implementing something like GSON's TypeToken, and my question is basically if I can achieve something better than my own suggestion that does not require sub-classing (or at least does not require passing type information through Class arguments or such) and does not force T to be a list.

Comment: You can't make the compiler to operate on types it doesn't know about, i.e. you can't enable methods based on a specific generic type hierarchy or prevent users from bypassing the intended api (as you correctly said it's still possible to pass a different subclass of `AbstractCallback`. Thus you'd either have to let the dev chose (in terms of subclasses, factory methods etc.) or operate on runtime data and throw exceptions where the types don't fit (e.g. a wrong callback has been set).

Comment: Another problem with your approach would be that you provide one generic type `T` but need two in some cases (i.e. in the case of `T = List<E>` you need the type `E` as well), but you don't want to provide that second type. Additionally your approach with `AbstractCallback<List<E>>` would work for marker interfaces but you wouldn't be able to directly call any method which involves the generic type on the passed callback, at least not without a cast.

Comment: Correct, but the callback will only be invoked when data has been supplied, and at that time I can check if T is a list. I realize that I will not be able to find the type of the elements and may have to resort to reflection in order to invoke the callback, but at least with the AbstractCallback approach the client will get some help from the IDE.

Comment: As it looks now I will probably go for a completely stand-alone type E declared as a generic method type. Clients registering the wrong type of callback will have to face a ClassCastException, unfortunately it cannot be thrown until it's time to invoke the callback.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you want to force T to be a List. If you do, you can use two generic type parameters - one for the element and another for the `List` :

```
class Test<E,T extends List<E>> {
  private T data;
  public void setData(T t) {data = t;}
  public T getData() { return data; }
}
```

Now you can write methods in Test that use E. For example :

```
public E getFirst ()
{
    if (data != null && data.size() > 0)
        return data.get(0);
     else
        return null;
}
```

Or you can eliminate T and just use E :

```
class Test<E> {
  private List<E> data;
  public void setData(List<E> t) {data = t;}
  public List<E> getData() { return data; }
}
```

Comment: We thought alike it seems... But it also seems that you understood more of the OP's intent than I did :)

Comment: This is an approach I didn't think of, but no, I do not want to *force* T into being a List, but *if* it is a List I want to be able to operate on E, where E is the type of the elements in the list.

Comment: @JHH then read my comment; however, this would basically require two separate classes, would it not?

Comment: Well, ideally I do not want a separate sub-class, see above for rationale, and I most definitely do not want to force T to be a list. I listed a solution myself which fulfills these requirements, but has other problems (somewhat ambigious API). What I'm looking for are potential other solutions that I may have overlooked, that also do not require separate classes or force T to be a list. :)

Comment: @JHH No, you can't do that.  Java's type system does not let you express constraints like "if this is of some particular type then work with it like this."

Answer (score -2):

Simply provide method generic parameters:

```
public <K extends List<T>> void setData(K t) {
  data = t;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
 objRef.setData(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

This method *enforces* you to pass as an argument the list of type *T* which is bound to the class.

Comment: No. This is the opposite of what I'm trying to do. Please read my entire post.

Comment: On second thought, maybe it was harsh to say this was the opposite. I actually didn't see that it was the setData method you had changed. But I do not want to force T into being a list, so setData should not mention lists at all. It's the setCallback method that should take an argument of type E, where E is "element-of" T (if, and only if, T is in fact a list), so to speak.